# Bootstrapping Drupal: Cannot redeclare function

Tags: bootstrapping

I'm trying to bootstrap Drupal (I'm making a rather simple bridge that automaticly logs a user into Drupal when they sign into PhpBB). I have the following code placed in the succes scenario of a succesful PhpBB login:

```
// DrupalBridge
function drupalbridge_login($username, $password)
{
    define('DRUPAL_ROOT', getcwd() . "/..");

    require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/bootstrap.inc';
    drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);

    global $user;

    $account = user_authenticate($username, $password);

    // Woah, it seems like we don't know this user, let's create him!
    if (!$account) {
        $userinfo = array(
            'name' => $name,
            'pass' => $pass,
            'init' => $name,
            'status' => 1,
            'access' => REQUEST_TIME,
        );
        $account = user_save(drupal_anonymous_user(), $userinfo);
        $loadme = user_authenticate($name, $pass);
    }

    $user = user_load($loadme, TRUE);
    drupal_session_regenerate();
}
//\DrupalBridge
```

This function works perfectly on its own. The problem is that this is in a giant file in the PhpBB system, where the `user_delete()` function is already defined, causing a `Fatal error: Cannot redeclare user_delete()`. The `user_delete()` function is deep inside the PhpBB core so I can't just rename that function either.

How can I solve this problem while still maintaining the functionality?

**==Update==**
I managed to fix the problem with the overlapping functions by changing the user_delete to phpbb_user_delete, as phpbb will also work with the phpbb_ prefix but I've run in to another problem now: [Drupal bootstrap external login from subfolder isn't working](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/77338/drupal-bootstrap-external-login-from-subfolder-isnt-working/)

Thanks in advance,
Silox

Comment: I have to say I think this is off-topic. This is a PHP namespacing issue, and doesn't relate to Drupal.

Comment: When I wanted to boostrap PhpBB into Drupal, I could prefix the PhpBB methods with `phpbb_`. So if it could be fixed in the same way, this would be on-topic.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of mashing the Drupal bootstrap into PHPBB, you could authenticate the user via an external API request to Drupal,

For example, using the [Services](https://drupal.org/project/services) module, with session authentication.

```
curl --data "username=test&password=pass" https://www.example.com/api/rest/user/login
```

Comment: Thank you for your anwser. I installed the Services module and got the curl working but I was wondering: Is the login persistent? If I execute the curl request in PHP, and I navigate to the Drupal section of the site, will the user be still logged in?

Comment: If you pass the session id information returned with the login request in subsequent requests, the user will be authenticated as that user.

Comment: Then I'm afraid this isn't the proper solution for what I want to do. I'm using Drupal in combination with PhpBB. When a user logs into PhpBB, I want him to be logged in to Drupal too. I can't know when the user will go back to the Drupal section of the site so I can't keep on passing the sid around on PhpBB part of the site, never knowing when the user might go to the Drupal section.

Answer (score 0):

You could perhaps work around this by renaming the functions inside your block using http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename-function.php

Just be careful, you're dealing with PECL stuff ;)

Comment: One would presumably still have to patch user_delete to look at the incoming args and have it determine which function to actually call, which is less than pretty.

Answer (score 0):

The only on-topic solution I can think of is to move to Drupal 8, which uses name spaces.

You could of course also do something like `sed s/user_delete/drupal_user_delete/g`, though that's going to be very complicated, given false positives and such.