# Bootstrap external login from subfolder isn't working

Tags: bootstrapping

Consider the following script.

```
define('DRUPAL_ROOT', getcwd() . "/..");

require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/bootstrap.inc';
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);

$username = "Silox";
$password = "hidden";

global $user;

$account = user_authenticate($username, $password);

// Woah, it seems like we don't know this user, let's create him!
if (!$account) {
    $userinfo = array(
        'name' => $username,
        'pass' => $password,
        'init' => $username,
        'status' => 1,
        'access' => REQUEST_TIME,
    );
    $account = user_save(drupal_anonymous_user(), $userinfo);
    $account = user_authenticate($username, $password);
}

$user = user_load($account, TRUE);
drupal_session_regenerate();
?>
```

This script logs me in or creates a new account when the username and password combination doesn't exist. When I put this script in the base directory of my Drupal installation, everything works perfectly fine.

However, when I put it in the root directory of the PhpBB subdirectory and change the `DRUPAL_ROOT` to `getcwd() . "/.."` to compensate for the extra folder, it doesn't work. If I print out my user array at the end of the function, I get a nice array with corresponding correct info but however, if I return to my Drupal site, I am not logged in.

How can this problem get solved?

Comment: +1 I'm currently having a similar issue, check out my question http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/79807/loading-bootstrap-inc-in-external-php-file-in-a-subdirectory Hope we can get it sorted soon

Answer (score 0):

I think this is related to how you're defining the `DRUPAL_ROOT` constant.

Several times I've had to make scripts interact with Drupal from sub folders, and I've found the simplest way to make sure things work correctly is to preface my code with the following:

```
<?php
chdir('../');
require_once './includes/bootstrap.inc';
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);
?>
```

The key thing here is the `chdir()` call.

Also, when creating a path and you want to go up one folder, its usually `../` not `/..`, because directory paths should usually end with a `/`.

Comment: Thank you for your solution but sadly, after I added the `chdir` and removed the `/..` it didn't work. The `/..` is actually right since getcwd() leaves out the trailing slash, so I have to compensate for it. The `./` of the require takes care ot the trailing slash.

Comment: Drupal 7 uses the `DRUPAL_ROOT` constant. If it's not defined, it will throw warnings.