# Loading bootstrap.inc in external PHP file in a subdirectory

Tags: 7, users, bootstrapping

I'm trying to check if there is a user logged into drupal in a PHP script that resides within a subdirectory of the drupal root. I know that there can be issues with calling the bootstrap anywhere apart from in the drupal root, so I've created a `drupal_bridge.inc.php` file inside the root containing the following code, which I then call in the PHP script using `include`.

```
<?php 

define("DRUPAL_ROOT",     "/var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/httpdocs/");

$current_wd = getcwd();

chdir(DRUPAL_ROOT);

print getcwd();

require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/bootstrap.inc';


global $base_url;

$base_url = (array_key_exists('HTTPS', $_SERVER) ? 'https://' : 'http://') . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];

drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);

chdir($current_wd);

global $user;

if ($user->uid) {
    print "Logged in";
} else {
   print "Logged out";
}

echo 'INCLUDED';

?>
```

However, when I visit the PHP script in the browser it says I am logged out. Strangely though if I visit the `drupal_bridge.inc.php` file directly it can access the user information and it says that I am logged in.

I have set `$cookie_domain = .mysite.com` in the settings file as well. I have password protected the directory containing the PHP script but I didn't think that made a difference at this level.

Any ideas?

Also, I have looked into turning this in a module but it is not really practical so I would appreciate it if you did not advise doing so.

**UPDATE**: I just did a `print_r($GLOBALS);` to see if I could find out what was actually available and I found the following errors, if that helps.
http://pastebin.com/YtHPGD75 (too long to post here)

Comment: your bootstrap and "real" Drupal installation are generating two different sessions, perhaps?   echo out the sessionid and compare the two.

Comment: @jdu Yes, I can confirm the two session id's are different. Any idea why this may be?

Comment: can you print_r($user) ? I have a feeling you're loading hte Anon user in your boostrap script.

Comment: @jdu I added `print_r($user);` to the above code and nothing is printed in the PHP script, but if I go to `drupal_bride.inc.php` I can see the full object for the user that is currently logged in.

Answer (score 1):

The bare minimum required is:

```
define('DRUPAL_ROOT', '/var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/httpdocs/');
$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] = 'mysite.com';
$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] = '127.0.0.1';
require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/bootstrap.inc';
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);
```

If you don't want to fully bootstrap and only get the session, see the technique defined in [Getting the current user without bootstrapping to DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_SESSION](https://drupal.org/node/1922406)

Comment: Thank you for your answer but unfortunately this issue was not due to the bootstrap code. Please see my answer

Answer (score 1):

After some time, and lots of experimentation, I have a solution at last thanks to [a discussion on osTicket](http://www.osticket.com/forums/forum/osticket-1-7-latest-release/mods-and-customizations-aa/9910-integrate-with-drupal-7?t=14959&goto=newpost). Unfortunately the issue was less due to Drupal, more down to osTicket and the fact that I had *included* the 'drupal bridge' in the wrong file. However an important note to make is that a drupal bridge - a file residing inside the Drupal root directory including bootstrap code - must be used to access session information in external scripts, rather than using the bootstrap code directly.

I hope that somebody will find this useful.

Comment: Your idea of a bridge/proxy script is clever.

Answer (score 0):

setting the `$base_url` in settings.php rather than leave Drupal to resolve it will solve the problem.